# Spots on Magnolia

Tags: trees, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, pest-control

My Kay Parris Magnolia has some odd white spots on it. I’m wondering what these could be and how to deal with them?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: Melbourne, Australia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things here:

- some of the spots look like they do not come off. Likely a bacterial infection
- there are clusters of insects and webbing that might be whitefly

If the tree is in good health it will tolerate both these. An inspection of drainage, soil moisture any other stress factors would be a good idea.

A picture of the whole tree would be helpful too.